# How to call js extern function from asp net page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have this page in `cshtml`.
This page execute submit in "formImpressao" (ASP.NET PAGE)

CSHTML page

```
@using Web.Mvc.Helpers
@{
    string msgSucesso = "test";      
}
<div id="divSucess">
<h5 style="background-image: url('themes/base/images/48/ico_ok.gif'); text-align:center; background-repeat: no-repeat; font-family: Verdana; color: #1d7100; font-size:'72'">@msgSucesso</h5>
</div>


<div id="HiddenFormTarget" style="display:none;">
    <form id="formImpressao" method="post" target="frmPrint" action="/VisualizarRelatorios/ImprimirRelatorio.aspx"></form>
</div>
<iframe id="frmPrint" name="frmPrint" width="0" height="0" runat="server">
</iframe>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#formImpressao").submit();
</script>
```

ASPX Page (ImprimirRelatorio.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ImprimirRelatorio.aspx.cs" Inherits="Views.Views.ImprimirRelatorios.ImprimirRelatorio" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<%--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">--%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px">

    <form id="form1" runat="server"  style=" width:100%; height:100%;" >
    <div style=" width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:hidden" >
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptRelatorio" runat="server" Width="100%"
            Height="100%" ProcessingMode="Remote" >
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script language="javascript">

    function Imprimir()
    {
        var viewer = $find("rptRelatorio");
        var isLoading = viewer.get_isLoading();
        var impresso = false;

        if (!isLoading) {
            $("input[type='image']:not(:disabled)[title*='Print']").click();
            impresso = true;
        }

        if (!impresso) {
            setTimeout(Imprimir, 1000);
        }else {
          $("#divSucess").style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
        }

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(Imprimir, 4000);
    });

</script>
```

The `Imprimir` function on validates whether the report was printed within Reporting Services.

If printed, it needs to assign to div `divSuccess`, the attribute: `style.backgroundColor = "red"`.

The problem is that the asp form does not see the `divSuccess` and the cshtml page does not display the asp form.

How can I call a js function inside the asp page to play the DOM of the page that has the "`divSuccess`"?

Are there other ways to do this?

The two pages do not talk.

Answer (score 0):

You could send AJAX request to get content of *ImprimirRelatorio.aspx* page. In success handler you could parse response to get inner HTML of body tag of the *ImprimirRelatorio.aspx* page, set result to some container (without `<iframe>`) and call `Imprimir` function (see details in [AJAX documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)). Note, the `Imprimir` function should be a part of success event handler of should be defined in the calling page.